Is the usage of Quit button banned for iOS apps? What if I publish an app with a Quit button?
I was editing the menu for a Ren'Py project and i found this:

if renpy.variant("pc"):

            ## The quit button is banned on iOS and unnecessary on Android and
            ## Web.
            textbutton _("Quit") action Quit(confirm=not main_menu)

What if I delete the
if renpy.variant("pc"):

block and place the Quit button directly? Will I get restricted or something like that?

This question is similar to: Would a button to exit my iPhone app be in violation of Apple's guidelines?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There is no strict "rule" prohibiting Quit button in an iOS app. You can include a button that "quits" your app if it serves a meaningful purpose. And it is also very straightforward to program it.
However, Apple's iOS user experience guidelines discourage including a Quit option solely to mimic the behavior found in desktop apps.
Unlike desktop applications, mobile apps are designed for quick switching rather than frequent quitting. Both iOS and Android optimize hardware resource sharing among active apps. Additionally, mobile user experience emphasizes single-app focus, whereas desktop environments allow users to view and interact with multiple apps simultaneously.
Some iOS apps in the App Store do provide a "Quit" option, but only when justified. For example, iOS app for 1Password, a popular password manager allows users to quit the app after removing a vault from the device.
If your app has a valid reason for a Quit feature and complies with Apple's guidelines, it has a good chance of passing App Store review.

Quit buttons are banned from the apple app store, as they ruin the seamless user experience that Apple wish to provide, as Ios has it's own way to open and close applications.
